# i want to sort variables which contains numbers in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm working on a project and what i want to do is to sort a variable which contains numbers..like 123546 etc..now I want to sort them like 123456 etc if it's in variable then its great, but if it's in array then also great.

Comment: can you give a code example which demonstrates what you are about to do?

Comment: You need to store them in an array, otherwise it's just a number or string. You will need some type of conversion.

Answer (score 3):

This should take care of it, assuming all numbers are in fact singular.

```
$numbers = str_split('123546');

sort($numbers);

echo join('', $numbers);
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3hXQ29)

It uses `str_split()` to turn the string into an array, the array is then sorted and then joined together.

Comment: any other way ? by doing it using array ?

Comment: @user2273901 `$numbers` is an array, no?

Comment: thanks a lot it's wokring! :) you are great :)

Comment: @user2273901 You're welcome. Since your new here, check the [about] page on how to accept answers.